# Why can I not scp using appleboy/scp-action@master but can locally using scp?

Tags: github-actions, scp

I have the following...

```
  - name: Build
    run: npm run build
  - name: Check the output
    run: ls -l build
  - name: Upload to EC2
    uses: appleboy/scp-action@master
    with:
      host: ${{ secrets.CBUS_HA_HOST }}
      username: github-actions
      key: ${{ secrets.AWS_PRIVATE_KEY }}
      source: ./build/*
      target: /usr/share/nginx/html
```

This maps to the equivalent functioning scp command locally

```
scp -v -r -i ~/Downloads/My.pem ./build/* github-actions@cbusha:/usr/share/nginx/html
```

But when I run I see the files...

```
Run ls -l build
total 52
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker 7289 Jun  8 21:57 asset-manifest.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker 3870 Jun  8 21:57 favicon.ico
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker 1102 Jun  8 21:57 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker 5347 Jun  8 21:57 logo192.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker 9664 Jun  8 21:57 logo512.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker  492 Jun  8 21:57 manifest.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker   67 Jun  8 21:57 robots.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 runner docker 4096 Jun  8 21:57 sitemap
```

But when it tries to upload I get...

```
Run appleboy/scp-action@master
...
 tar all files into /tmp/LnbGTePEvj.tar.gz
remote server os type is unix
scp file to server.
Remove target folder: /usr/share/nginx/html
drone-scp error:  Process exited with status 1
drone-scp rollback: remove all target tmp file
remove file LnbGTePEvj.tar.gz
2023/06/08 22:22:32 Process exited with status 1
```

How do I do this properly like the command I can run locally?

Comment: Looks like someone has already reported this issue: https://github.com/appleboy/scp-action/issues/119